# Does AGM-Map support everything that Google Maps API does?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

Hi all I am creating an Angular 6 project and I am looking to implement asset tracking utilizing google maps api. However, I was wondering if AGM-Map supports everything Google Maps Api does such as heatmaps, and asset tracking because I can only seem to find basic placing markers and circles on a map.

Comment: When I tried this library it lacked cluster [click event](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer) (still does). I know it is not core google map api, but it is usefull.

Comment: I have used it a lot and I haven't got to a point where it was lacking something the api. There's a chatroom for it too and people are constantly asking questions and we help them out

Comment: They also have Discord [room](https://discordapp.com/invite/XAr2ACE)

Comment: Here are some helpful links:

https://github.com/googlemaps/transport-tracker ,
https://medium.com/@balramchavan/display-and-track-users-current-location-using-google-map-geolocation-in-angular-5-c259ec801d58 ,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-bus-tracking,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-bus-tracking

Comment: Thanks all for the very helpful resources. One last question how would I go about removing the previous marker when I add the new marker with the new lat/lng?

Comment: @PatricioVargas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will say the majority of the functionality of the Google Maps is in AGM, if not you can get your questions answered in the official forum. Also, there are a lot of dependencies that people created to fill this functionalities that were missing.

Here's a small demo, showing how to use the map and showing how to use a marker from the map. This map will add a new marker wherever you click on the map and if you click on a marker it will erase it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-d9iec2

**HTML**

```
  <agm-map 
      [latitude]="lat"
      [longitude]="lng"
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [disableDefaultUI]="false"
      [zoomControl]="false"
      (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)">

      <agm-marker 
          *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
          (markerClick)="eraseMarker(m)"
          [latitude]="m.lat"
          [longitude]="m.lng"
          [label]="m.label">
      </agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
```

**TS**

```
eraseMarker( marker: Marker) {
    const positionArray = this.markers.indexOf(marker);
    this.markers.splice(positionArray, 1);
    console.log(this.markers);
  }
```

Also reference this for the heat map:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-overlays
2. https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1423
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-heatmap